# Linq Expression on sub child entities for n levels

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

Need Generic expression for the below Query.

```
I don't want to use the Dynamic library and Predicate builder.
```

I am generating expressions dynamically.

```
var test = entity.User.Where(PUser => PUser.Role.TeamRoles.Any(PTeamRoles => PTeamRoles.TeamId == "222")));
```

I would like generate dynamic expression for one-to-one and then many relational query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the soltuion

Expression proeprtyexpression = Expression.Property(PTeamRoles, "TeamId");
            Expression valueexpress = Expression.Constant("A");
            //Expression innerexpression = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(proeprtyexpression, valueexpress), PTeamRoles);
            Expression innerexpression = Expression.Lambda(ExcelExpressionHelper.ApplyOperator(proeprtyexpression, valueexpress, "StartsWith"), PTeamRoles);

```
        Type winnertype = PTeamRoles.Type;
        Type woutertype = PRole.Type;
        var wouterProperty = Expression.Property(PRole, "TeamRoles");

        var outerMethodExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { winnertype }, wouterProperty, innerexpression);
```